# Почему картинка не показывается в списке вместо маркера?

Tags: html, css

Всё, что нужно - использовать картинку вместо маркеров списка.
Мой код:

```css
a{
    text-decoration:none;
}
body, html{
    font-family: 'Kurale', serif;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    overflow:auto;
    min-height:100vh;
}
body{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    background-color:#f8f8f8;
    /* text-align:center; */
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
header{
    background-color:white;
    border:4px double black;
}
footer hr{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
footer p{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:16px;
}
input[text]{
    
}
.menu_hor{
    text-align:center;
    margin:3px;
    padding:3px;
}
.menu_hor li{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    text-align:center;
    background: #4876FF; 
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 18px;
}
.menu_hor li a{
    color: white; 
    display: block; 
    padding: 7px 20px; 
    text-decoration: none; 
}
.menu_hor li:hover{
    background: #B22222; 
    color: #fff;
}
.main{
    flex-grow:1;
    text-align:center;
}
.mylogo{
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
}
.mylogo span{
    left:30%;
    position:absolute;
    border-radius:2px;
    font-size:40px;
    padding:3px 5px;
}
.graphic_logo{
    height:250px;
    padding:5px;
    max-width:100%;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
.ctr {
    text-align: center;
    margin:0; 
    padding:0;
}
.headersProductCatalog h1, h3{
    margin:0; 
    padding:0;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:18px;
    font-weight:400;
    background-color:#eaeaea;
}
.headersProductCatalog p{
    margin:0; 
    padding:0;
}
.headersProductCatalog p.briefDescription{
    font-size:14px;
    font-style:italic;
    color:#707070;
    line-height:16px;
}
.headersProductCatalog p.detailedDescription{
    font-size:16px;
    font-style:italic;
    font-weight:400;
    color:#484343;
    line-height:24px;
    text-align:left;
}
.List ul{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
}
.List ul li{
    font-size:14px;
    font-style:italic;
    font-weight:600;
    line-height:30px;
    color:#484343;
    list-style-image:url("../Image/check1.png");
    /* padding: 4px 0 4px 20px; */
    /* margin:0; */
    /* background-image:url(../Image/check1.png); */
}
/* .List ul li::before{ */
    /* margin-right: 0.5em; */
    /* list-style-image:url(../Image/check1.png); */
/* } */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../Style/style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Kurale&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="includeHTML.js"></script>
    <title>Fantasy3gPhone</title>
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <div class="mylogo">
            <a href="../index.html"><img class="graphic_logo" src="../Image/logo.png" alt="logo"></a>
            <span>Магазин телефонов</span>
        </div>
    </header>
    
    <ul class="menu_hor">
        <li><a href="../index.html">Главная</a></li>
        <li><a href="../Registration.html">Зарегистрироваться</a></li>
        <li><a href="../Phones.html">Каталог товаров</a></li>
        <li><a href="../Contacts.html">Контакты</a></li>
    </ul>
    
    <div class="headersProductCatalog">
        <h1>Описание товара "Fantasy3gPhone"</h1>
        <p class="ctr">
            <img src="../Image/3gPhone.jpg" width=30% height=30% alt="phone">
        </p>
        <h3>Краткое описание товара:</h3>
        <p class="briefDescription">Fantasy3gPhone модель телефонов с кнопками - это стиль. Некоторые телефоны выполнены в стильном алюминиевом корпусе. 
        Эти модели имеют не только мощную начинку, которая исключает какие-либо сбои в работе устройства, но и могут стать подходящим атрибутом стиля делового человека.</p>
        <h3>Подробное описание товара:</h3>
        <p class="detailedDescription">В конструкцию аппарата встроена специальная клавиша, которая позволяет мгновенно активировать режим создания снимков селфи. 
        Кстати, неподалеку от модуля фронтальной камеры можно обнаружить глазок светодиодной вспышки. 
        Такое решение имеется далеко не во всех современных смартфонах, что повышает интерес к устройству в разы. 
        Снимками можно сразу же поделиться, использовав популярные приложения, разработанные для социальных сетей. 
        Корпус телефона изготовлен из поликарбоната. 
        Исключение составляет задняя панелька устройства. Она выполнена из металла (алюминий) с применением матового покрытия. 
        Утонченный дизайн наравне с высоким (причем весьма и весьма высоким) качеством сборки – вот что отличает данную модель. 
        Как говорилось ранее, в телефон встроена вспышка. 
        Из дополнительных возможностей также можно отметить аналоговое радио. 
        Эта модель телефона имеет модификацию. Различие между ними заключается в том, что в модификации есть сразу два слота для СИМ-карт.</p>
        <h3>Характеристики товара:</h3>
        
        <div class="List">
            <ul>
                <li>поддержка двух SIM-карт</li>
                <li>экран 2.8", разрешение 320x240</li>
                <li>камера 2 МП</li>
                <li>память 32 МБ, слот для карты памяти</li>
                <li>Bluetooth</li>
                <li>объем оперативной памяти 16 МБ</li>
                <li>аккумулятор 1200 мА⋅ч</li>
                <li>вес 92 г, ШxВxТ 53.40x124.60x10.90 мм</li>
                <li>MP3-плеер, радио</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        
        <h3>Внешний вид товара</h3>
        <p>Выглядит он, как обычный кнопочный телефон. Примечательно то, что он может работать "веками" и внешний вид не подвержен течению времени!</p>
    </div>
    
    <footer>
        <hr>
        <p>Все права защищены&copy 2020</p>
    </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если путь к картинке правильный, то проблема в обнулённых паддингах у body: картинка просто выходит за пределы экрана

```css
a{
    text-decoration:none;
}
body, html{
    font-family: 'Kurale', serif;
    margin:0;
    overflow:auto;
    min-height:100vh;
}
body{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    background-color:#f8f8f8;
    /* text-align:center; */
    box-sizing:border-box;
    padding: 0 70px;
}
header{
    background-color:white;
    border:4px double black;
}
footer hr{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
footer p{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:16px;
}
input[text]{
    
}
.menu_hor{
    text-align:center;
    margin:3px;
    padding:3px;
}
.menu_hor li{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    text-align:center;
    background: #4876FF; 
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 18px;
}
.menu_hor li a{
    color: white; 
    display: block; 
    padding: 7px 20px; 
    text-decoration: none; 
}
.menu_hor li:hover{
    background: #B22222; 
    color: #fff;
}
.main{
    flex-grow:1;
    text-align:center;
}
.mylogo{
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
}
.mylogo span{
    left:30%;
    position:absolute;
    border-radius:2px;
    font-size:40px;
    padding:3px 5px;
}
.graphic_logo{
    height:250px;
    padding:5px;
    max-width:100%;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
.ctr {
    text-align: center;
    margin:0; 
    padding:0;
}
.headersProductCatalog h1, h3{
    margin:0; 
    padding:0;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:18px;
    font-weight:400;
    background-color:#eaeaea;
}
.headersProductCatalog p{
    margin:0; 
    padding:0;
}
.headersProductCatalog p.briefDescription{
    font-size:14px;
    font-style:italic;
    color:#707070;
    line-height:16px;
}
.headersProductCatalog p.detailedDescription{
    font-size:16px;
    font-style:italic;
    font-weight:400;
    color:#484343;
    line-height:24px;
    text-align:left;
}
.List ul{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
}
.List ul li{
    font-size:14px;
    font-style:italic;
    font-weight:600;
    line-height:30px;
    color:#484343;
    list-style-image:url("http://files.softicons.com/download/toolbar-icons/free-mobile-icon-kit-by-happy-icon-studio/png/64x64/export_black.png");
    /* padding: 4px 0 4px 20px; */
    /* margin:0; */
    /* background-image:url(../Image/check1.png); */
}
/* .List ul li::before{ */
    /* margin-right: 0.5em; */
    /* list-style-image:url(../Image/check1.png); */
/* } */
```

```html
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Kurale&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <header>
        <div class="mylogo">
            <a href="../index.html"><img class="graphic_logo" src="../Image/logo.png" alt="logo"></a>
            <span>Магазин телефонов</span>
        </div>
    </header>
    
    <ul class="menu_hor">
        <li><a href="../index.html">Главная</a></li>
        <li><a href="../Registration.html">Зарегистрироваться</a></li>
        <li><a href="../Phones.html">Каталог товаров</a></li>
        <li><a href="../Contacts.html">Контакты</a></li>
    </ul>
    
    <div class="headersProductCatalog">
        <h1>Описание товара "Fantasy3gPhone"</h1>
        <p class="ctr">
            <img src="../Image/3gPhone.jpg" width=30% height=30% alt="phone">
        </p>
        <h3>Краткое описание товара:</h3>
        <p class="briefDescription">Fantasy3gPhone модель телефонов с кнопками - это стиль. Некоторые телефоны выполнены в стильном алюминиевом корпусе. 
        Эти модели имеют не только мощную начинку, которая исключает какие-либо сбои в работе устройства, но и могут стать подходящим атрибутом стиля делового человека.</p>
        <h3>Подробное описание товара:</h3>
        <p class="detailedDescription">В конструкцию аппарата встроена специальная клавиша, которая позволяет мгновенно активировать режим создания снимков селфи. 
        Кстати, неподалеку от модуля фронтальной камеры можно обнаружить глазок светодиодной вспышки. 
        Такое решение имеется далеко не во всех современных смартфонах, что повышает интерес к устройству в разы. 
        Снимками можно сразу же поделиться, использовав популярные приложения, разработанные для социальных сетей. 
        Корпус телефона изготовлен из поликарбоната. 
        Исключение составляет задняя панелька устройства. Она выполнена из металла (алюминий) с применением матового покрытия. 
        Утонченный дизайн наравне с высоким (причем весьма и весьма высоким) качеством сборки – вот что отличает данную модель. 
        Как говорилось ранее, в телефон встроена вспышка. 
        Из дополнительных возможностей также можно отметить аналоговое радио. 
        Эта модель телефона имеет модификацию. Различие между ними заключается в том, что в модификации есть сразу два слота для СИМ-карт.</p>
        <h3>Характеристики товара:</h3>
        
        <div class="List">
            <ul>
                <li>поддержка двух SIM-карт</li>
                <li>экран 2.8", разрешение 320x240</li>
                <li>камера 2 МП</li>
                <li>память 32 МБ, слот для карты памяти</li>
                <li>Bluetooth</li>
                <li>объем оперативной памяти 16 МБ</li>
                <li>аккумулятор 1200 мА⋅ч</li>
                <li>вес 92 г, ШxВxТ 53.40x124.60x10.90 мм</li>
                <li>MP3-плеер, радио</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        
        <h3>Внешний вид товара</h3>
        <p>Выглядит он, как обычный кнопочный телефон. Примечательно то, что он может работать "веками" и внешний вид не подвержен течению времени!</p>
    </div>
    
    <footer>
        <hr>
        <p>Все права защищены&copy 2020</p>
    </footer>
```

Comment: Спасибо, Вам!) Действительно в пэддинге дело было.)

Comment: @Genas, пожалуйста :)

Answer (score 1):

Чаще всего ошибка в указании пути к файлу. Ваш код работает если правильно указать путь к картинке

```css
.List ul li{
    font-size:14px;
    font-style:italic;
    font-weight:600;
    line-height:30px;
    color:#484343;
    list-style-image:url("//yastatic.net/s3/home/services/block/music1.svg");
    /* padding: 4px 0 4px 20px; */
    /* margin:0; */
    /* background-image:url(../Image/check1.png); */
}
```

```html
<div class="List">
            <ul>
                <li>поддержка двух SIM-карт</li>
                <li>экран 2.8", разрешение 320x240</li>
                <li>камера 2 МП</li>
                <li>память 32 МБ, слот для карты памяти</li>
                <li>Bluetooth</li>
                <li>объем оперативной памяти 16 МБ</li>
                <li>аккумулятор 1200 мА⋅ч</li>
                <li>вес 92 г, ШxВxТ 53.40x124.60x10.90 мм</li>
                <li>MP3-плеер, радио</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: путь к картинке правильный)) я посимвольно проверил.)